# PHP 4 Dates Wrong

Tags: php, mysql, date, unix-timestamp

According to Yahoo, my account is using MySQL 4.1.14, and PHP 4.  Yeah, I know I am a bit behind.  I noticed some funny things started going on with my code a while back, around dates.  But I thought time zone setting did not come into play until PHP 5.

Anyway, I am pulling dates from a database using `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`, and it gives me a timestamp like 1436745600 for a date 2015-07-13 stored in my database.  This looks correct to me.  But then my code simply does a `date('M-j','variable storing that number')`, and it gives me 'July-12'.  Why is this?

I know I am PST, and the server is UTC, but on version 4, how would PHP know that?  And even if it did, we are both on the same day for most of a 24 hour cycle.  As I started writing this, we were on the same day, and still the problem occurred.  As I finish, we are on different days, and the result is the same.  Something else going on here?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include a code snippet of your code.

Comment: What sort of account are you referring to? How does this relate to Yahoo? Do you use Yahoo for web hosting? (PHP4 and MySQL 4 is more than a "bit behind". It's probably now a security liability, and you should migrate to 5.x with some urgency).

Comment: It sounds like you have Pacific time set as the default timezone in `php.ini`. That timestamp is `2015-07-13 00:00 UTC`, which is `2015-07-12 17:00 PDT`

Comment: Use `date_default_timezone_set('UTC')` to make your script run in UTC.

Comment: PDT and UTC are in different days for 7 hours of the day: Everything from midnight to 06:59

Comment: PHP 4 and MySQL 4.1 have both been obsolete and unsupported for nearly 7 years. The software your host is providing here is *dangerously* old; you need to find a better web host immediately.